# Generar salida Array sin duplicar valores al tener varios metadatos

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Estoy trabajando con NodeJS, tengo un problema a la hora de tratar mis datos que me llegan de una suscripción a una API. Mi problema viene a la hora de tratar los metadatos ya que si vienen 7 recorro los 7 y género 7 nuevos objetos y necesitaria un objeto con la información de algunos de esos campos.

Codigo de mi suscripción:

```
{
   "subscriptionId":"5d5434a4a282bde1a8c8af53",
   "originator":"localhost",
   "contextResponses":[
      {
         "contextElement":{
            "type":"estacion",
            "isPattern":"false",
            "id":"pruebas999borrar22224442222333",
            "attributes":[
               {
                  "name":"CE_suelo",
                  "type":"float",
                  "value":3.86,
                  "metadatas":[
                     {
                        "name":"timestamp",
                        "type":"DateTime",
                        "value":"2019-08-02T11:57:40.00Z"
                     },
                     {
                        "name":"id",
                        "type":"String",
                        "value":"8"
                     },
                     {
                        "name":"name_comun",
                        "type":"String",
                        "value":"CE suelo"
                     },
                     {
                        "name":"type",
                        "type":"String",
                        "value":"fertigation"
                     },
                     {
                        "name":"place",
                        "type":"String",
                        "value":"interior"
                     },
                     {
                        "name":"img",
                        "type":"String",
                        "value":"assets/img/flash.png"
                     },
                     {
                        "name":"medida",
                        "type":"String",
                        "value":"mS/cm"
                     }
                  ]
               },
               {
                  "name":"Temp_suelo",
                  "type":"float",
                  "value":32.856,
                  "metadatas":[
                     {
                        "name":"timestamp",
                        "type":"DateTime",
                        "value":"2019-08-02T11:57:40.00Z"
                     },
                     {
                        "name":"id",
                        "type":"String",
                        "value":"5"
                     },
                     {
                        "name":"name_comun",
                        "type":"String",
                        "value":"Temp suelo"
                     },
                     {
                        "name":"type",
                        "type":"String",
                        "value":"fertigation"
                     },
                     {
                        "name":"place",
                        "type":"String",
                        "value":"interior"
                     },
                     {
                        "name":"img",
                        "type":"String",
                        "value":"assets/img/temp.png"
                     },
                     {
                        "name":"medida",
                        "type":"String",
                        "value":"ºC"
                     }
                  ]
               }
            ]
         },
         "statusCode":{
            "code":"200",
            "reasonPhrase":"OK"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Esto lo estoy recorriendo con for anidados y al entrar en metadatos lógicamente recorre los 7 metadatos y así los guarda en BD y no es lo correcto.

Este es mi codigo:

```
var data_inver = [];
    var asociar_inver = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < params.contextResponses.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < params.contextResponses[i].contextElement.attributes.length; j++) {
            for (var k = 0; k < params.contextResponses[i].contextElement.attributes[j].metadatas.length; k++) {
                //console.log('Mostramos el array:', params.contextResponses[i].contextElement.attributes[j].metadatas)
                if (params.contextResponses[i].contextElement.attributes[j].metadatas[k].name === 'timestamp') {
                    var recvTime = params.contextResponses[i].contextElement.attributes[j].metadatas[k].value;
                    //var recvTimeTs = new Date(params.contextResponses[i].contextElement.attributes[j].metadatas[k].value * 1000).toISOString();
                    var recvTimeTs = new Date(params.contextResponses[i].contextElement.attributes[j].metadatas[k].value).getTime() / 1000;
                    //var recvTimeTs = (new Date(params.contextResponses[i].contextElement.attributes[j].metadatas[k].value * 1000).getTime() / 1000).toString();
                    //console.log('Mostramos este valor:', recvTime, recvTimeTs)
                    console.log('Primer IF')

                }
                if ((params.contextResponses[i].contextElement.attributes[j].metadatas[k].name === 'id')) {
                    var id_fiware = params.contextResponses[i].contextElement.attributes[j].metadatas[k].value;
                    //console.log('Mostramos este valor:', id_fiware)
                    console.log('Segundo IF', id_fiware)

                }
                var medidas_inver = {
                    id_station: params.contextResponses[i].contextElement.id,
                    fiware_service: paramsheadersFiware_Service,
                    fiware_servicepath: paramsheadersFiware_ServicePath,
                    attrName: params.contextResponses[i].contextElement.attributes[j].name,
                    //id_sensor_station_absolute: params.contextResponses[i].contextElement.attributes[j].name.concat("_", params.contextResponses[i].contextElement.id),
                    //id_sensor_station_absolute: id_fiware.concat("_", params.contextResponses[i].contextElement.id),
                    attrType: params.contextResponses[i].contextElement.attributes[j].type,
                    attrValue: params.contextResponses[i].contextElement.attributes[j].value,
                    recvTimeTs: recvTimeTs,
                    recvTime: recvTime,
                    id: id_fiware
                };
                data_inver.push(medidas_inver);
                console.log('Mostramos las medidas:', JSON.stringify(data_inver));
            }
        }
    }
```

Compruebo si el metadato es timestamp para guardarlo en una variable y lo mismo con id el resultado final tiene que ser asi con cada uno de los elementos separando por , cada objeto.

{"id_station":"pruebas999borrar22224442222333","attrName":"CE_suelo","attrType":"float","attrValue":3.86,"recvTimeTs":1564747060,"recvTime":"2019-08-02T11:57:40.00Z","id":"8"}]

Y mi programa hace lo siguiente duplicar por tantos metadatos tenga ya que guarda 14 valores en base de datos y tendría que ser solo 2.

```
[{"id_station":"pruebas999borrar22224442222333","attrName":"CE_suelo","attrType":"float","attrValue":3.86,"recvTimeTs":1564747060,"recvTime":"2019-08-02T11:57:40.00Z"},{"id_station":"pruebas999borrar22224442222333","attrName":"CE_suelo","attrType":"float","attrValue":3.86,"recvTimeTs":1564747060,"recvTime":"2019-08-02T11:57:40.00Z","id":"8"}]
```

gracias un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

No sé que querés guardar exactamnte, pero una forma bastante corta es haciendo `reduce()` y `forEach()`'s este es un ejémplo que creo que se acerca bastante a lo que querés hacer. Asumí que el criterio de agrupamiento es el timestamp, pero funcionaría igual si fuera otro.

```js
const dataApi = {
  "subscriptionId": "5d5434a4a282bde1a8c8af53",
  "originator": "localhost",
  "contextResponses": [{
    "contextElement": {
      "type": "estacion",
      "isPattern": "false",
      "id": "pruebas999borrar22224442222333",
      "attributes": [{
          "name": "CE_suelo",
          "type": "float",
          "value": 3.86,
          "metadatas": [{
              "name": "timestamp",
              "type": "DateTime",
              "value": "2019-08-02T11:57:40.00Z"
            },
            {
              "name": "id",
              "type": "String",
              "value": "8"
            },
            {
              "name": "name_comun",
              "type": "String",
              "value": "CE suelo"
            },
            {
              "name": "type",
              "type": "String",
              "value": "fertigation"
            },
            {
              "name": "place",
              "type": "String",
              "value": "interior"
            },
            {
              "name": "img",
              "type": "String",
              "value": "assets/img/flash.png"
            },
            {
              "name": "medida",
              "type": "String",
              "value": "mS/cm"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Temp_suelo",
          "type": "float",
          "value": 32.856,
          "metadatas": [{
              "name": "timestamp",
              "type": "DateTime",
              "value": "2019-08-02T11:57:40.00Z"
            },
            {
              "name": "id",
              "type": "String",
              "value": "5"
            },
            {
              "name": "name_comun",
              "type": "String",
              "value": "Temp suelo"
            },
            {
              "name": "type",
              "type": "String",
              "value": "fertigation"
            },
            {
              "name": "place",
              "type": "String",
              "value": "interior"
            },
            {
              "name": "img",
              "type": "String",
              "value": "assets/img/temp.png"
            },
            {
              "name": "medida",
              "type": "String",
              "value": "ºC"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    "statusCode": {
      "code": "200",
      "reasonPhrase": "OK"
    }
  }]
}


const timeStamp = dataApi.contextResponses.reduce((p, c) => {
  c.contextElement.attributes.forEach(e => {
    e.metadatas.forEach(m => {
      if (m.name === "timestamp") {
        const obj = {}
        obj.id_station = c.contextElement.id;
        obj.attrName = e.name;
        obj.attrType = e.type;
        obj.attrValue = e.value;
        obj.recvTimeTs = m.value;
        obj.recvTime = m.value;
        p.push(obj)
      }
    })
  })
  return p;
}, []);

console.log(timeStamp);
```

Comment: hola estoy comprobando la salida y no termina de ser la correcta necesitaria tambien añadir la información del campo "id" a ese objeto como podría hacerlo? la salida correcta seria esta: {"id_station":"pruebas999borrar22224442222333","attrName":"CE_suelo","attrType":"float","attrValue":3.86,"recvTimeTs":1564747060,"recvTime":"2019-08-02T11:57:40.00Z","id":"8"}]

Comment: hola ya lo he solucionado sacando del For el objeto y al buscar en los IF los dos metadatos guardandolos en variables. Un saludo